# Write number in excel cells using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How can I write my full value in cell with help of poi ?

i.e. if value is 1000.000 then how can I write this full value without truncating 000 after "."  with POI? means I want full value.

In my case, it only takes 1000 but this is not right format for me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to set "Format" of the cell where this number is getting stored. Example code:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("format sheet");
CellStyle style;
DataFormat format = wb.createDataFormat();
Row row;
Cell cell;
short rowNum = 0;
short colNum = 0;

row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
cell = row.createCell(colNum);
cell.setCellValue(11111.25);
style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0.0"));
cell.setCellStyle(style);

row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
cell = row.createCell(colNum);
cell.setCellValue(11111.25);
style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#,##0.0000"));
cell.setCellStyle(style);

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Source : http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats

Comment: can i use absolute value with poi API..? and if yes then how..?

Comment: Yes, if you provide 10, it would be displayed as 10.000 if proper Format is set for the cell.

Comment: thank you so much..... but now my que is how can i write absolute ? value like -50 will be display as 50

Comment: Use this format: ######.###;######.### it would display -50.123 as 50.123