# Setting Excel cell value in Numeric format using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to store numeric data in excel sheet.
The numeric data is represented by String type in my java code.
Is it possible to set it as numeric without casting it?

I've tried the following code, but it wasn't converted to numeric type (I get a warning in excel saying that number is stored as text...)

```
HSSFCell dCell =...
dCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
dCell.setCellValue("112.45")
```

Comment: Isn't the setCellValue method overloaded to support other types, i.e. can't you pass a float or something into that method? You are currently passing a string.

Comment: Yes, I can pass any type. I asked if its possible to pass value AS String and auto-convert it to the needed type.

Comment: see this: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335285/write-number-in-excel-cell-with-poi

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to provide the value as a double. As [the doc says](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#setCellValue%28boolean%29):

> **setCellValue**
>
> `public void setCellValue(double value)`
>
> set a numeric value for the cell
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> *value* - the numeric value to set this cell to. For formulas we'll set the
>   precalculated value, for numerics we'll set its value. For other types
>   we will change the cell to a numeric cell and set its value.

So, it should be

```
dCell.setCellValue(new Double("123"));
```

OR

```
dCell.setCellValue(123);  //Remember, the way you did was, you actually passed a string (no quotes)
```

Comment: so I must set value in the needed type? it can't be "auto-converted" from String?

Comment: No, simply use what I said or dCell.setCellValue(123). Remember, no quotes or it will make it a string. (which you actually did)

Answer (score 8):

I used Big Decimal for this,

```
dCell.setCellValue(new BigDecimal("112.45").doubleValue());
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for Big decimal conversion too.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use wrapper classes:

```
dCell.setCellValue(new Double(112.45));
```

BTW, it will work if you simply give the value instead of the double cotes as follows:

```
dCell.setCellValue(112.45);
```

Answer (score 1):

Old one But Still it This will help Some one from .NET who use NPOI

```
dCell.setCellValue(Convert.ToDouble(112.45));
```

We do have

```
cell.SetCellType(NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.NUMERIC);
```

which doesn't remove the warning but the 1st code did worked after converting to Double for All integers and Double values in .net