# Data mismatch while copy to * CSV file

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, csv

Runnning sql query to export the contents to CSV file i notice that certain columns do not get displayed properly.in my cast date timestamp is not properly displayed in cell

**Code as below :**

```
  COPY  (select hostname as "Host Name",devicetype as "Device Type",platform as "Model",Ipaddress as "IP Address",swversion as "Software Version",configuredTime as "Configured",activeTime as "Active",cluster as "Clusters",location as "Location",macaddress as "Mac Address",devicepool as "Device Pool" from (select getmodelinfo.ipaddress,max(getmodelinfo.hostname) as
            hostname, max(getmodelinfo.macaddress) as macaddress,
            max(getmodelinfo.devicetype) as devicetype,
            max(getmodelinfo.platform) as platform,
            max(getmodelinfo.swversion) as swversion, min(getmodelinfo.day_end_date) as configuredtime,
            max(getmodelinfo.active_end_date) as activetime,
            max(getmodelinfo.ucmclustername)
            as cluster, max(getmodelinfo.ucmlocation) as location,
            max(getmodelinfo.ucmdevicepool) as devicepool from (select
            pcwh_inv.uniquedeviceid,pcwh_inv.ipaddress,
            pcwh_inv.endpointmodel, pcwh_inv.hostname, pcwh_inv.devicetype, pcwh_inv.platform,
            pcwh_inv.macaddress, pcwh_inv.version as
            swversion,pcwh_inv.deployed_day_end_date as day_end_date,
            pcwh_inv.lastupdated_day_end_date as active_end_date,
            pcwh_inv.ucmclustername,pcwh_inv.ucmlocation,pcwh_inv.ucmdevicepool
            from pcwh_inventory_20160410 pcwh_inv,
            (select pcwh_inv.uniquedeviceid, max(pcwh_inv.lastupdated_day_end_date) as
            lasttime from pcwh_inventory_20160410 pcwh_inv where pcwh_inv.ipaddress
            notnull group by
            pcwh_inv.uniquedeviceid)gettime where pcwh_inv.endpointmodel = 'SX' and
            pcwh_inv.uniquedeviceid = gettime.uniquedeviceid and
            pcwh_inv.lastupdated_day_end_date = gettime.lasttime and  pcwh_inv.mgmtstatus not in ('Deleted')
                )getmodelinfo group by ipaddress) M) TO '/opt/emms/emsam/export/raj2.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

Please find below screenshot of the result I get on running query without exporting to csv , on export to csv (image below) , image of cell content when i click on particular row content it shows correctly though(bottom most image)
[image: Below is the image file of result]

It seems to me an issue with formatting csv file could you please let me know how I could do this from query level to display exact contents as in db column?

Comment: If you open the CSV in Notepad or the like instead of Excel, what do you see in that column?

Comment: I see the whole content as it is supposed to be read @William

Answer (score 2):

I believe nothing is wrong with your code, but that Excel is treating that column as something other than a date, this happens often. It can be resolved by selecting all of the affected cells, right clicking, and changing the format to text through the subsequent menus.

If this CSV is going to be manipulated further by another application, I don't think you will have an issue, as the data is seemingly fine.

If for whatever reason you need it to be correctly displayed in Excel dynamically, you may need to look into something like this.. [Java - Excel Cell Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967942/setting-excel-cell-value-in-numeric-format-using-poi)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is straight forward there is no error with CSV format.Actually the data entries done by you are in the wrong way u can't have a space in a data entry that will cause a problem.
So in the 6th and 7th column u can see there is a space between the data entries so due to which problem is taking place.
To prevent that just add a new column for date.
It will solve all the problems and the data will be entered in your database.

Comment: the thing is I am just pulling data from DB as it is and displaying i do not have control on how db stores data.Although i do not see te exact value in cell when i click on it I get to see the full data as shown in the 3'rd image below

Comment: Ya but just remember a thing in data entry u can just enter only one element multiple things cant be added under the same coloumn