# Apache poi - Thousand separator

Tags: java, format, apache-poi

Do you know how can I set the thousand sepator and have a value formatted like this? `403.000`

I'm using apache-poi 3.8 with Java.
I googled it a lot but I didn't find an answer. I can't use a string value because my formulas are not evaluated correctly in this way. Any help? thanks!

I've tried something like this:

```
cellStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("#.##0"));
```

but it doesn't work..

Comment: Try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335285/write-number-in-excel-cell-with-poi

Comment: @Shane, that question is related to decimals value, I need to have the sepator for thousand, so, if my value is 1000000, I want to show 1.000.000

Comment: How would you do that in Excel? And did you try asking POI to do it the same way that you would do in Excel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question for everyone else who might have the same issue.

found it: the format must be: `"#,##0"`

`dataCell.getCellStyle().setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0"));`

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
 final HSSFCell dataCell = dataRow.createCell(1);
 dataCell.getCellStyle().setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0"));
 dataCell.setCellValue(123456);
```

You'll have a cell with the number display like this: 123.456
The thousand separator depends of the locale and perhaps of the language of excel.