# CSV in Excel: Floating point >=1 displayed as hashtags

Tags: java, excel, csv, floating-point

I am writing values in a CSV file using Java. One column are floating point values. The values are written correctly - I checked using Notepad++. However, when I use Excel to open it all floating point values >= 1.0 are displayd as a series of hashtags. When I click the cell it contains the correct value, but with the floating point "." missing. The value in the screenshot should be 33.014782905578606.

[image: screenshot]

This is strange because I explicitly use "," as a separator and not "." as stated in the first line of the csv: `sep=,` Furthermore, all floating point values <1.0 are displayed correctly.

I hope this is not off topic.

Edit: Expanding the column width helped with the hashtags. But the floating point for values >=1 is still missing. Even if I used ";" instead of "," and remove the `sep=,`.

Comment: Expand the column width.

Comment: About the dot instead of the comma, that's because of your excel preferences. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27401312/1138559

Comment: @alkis: I don't really get it. Does this explain, why the dot is missing?

Comment: You mention that `This is strange because I explicitly use "," as a separator and not "."` . The dot separator is the default that excel uses on your machine. You are giving it a comma as the separator, but what excel "sees" is a separator in general. If you want to use comma as the separator, you don't change something to your code, you just open the excel file and change the preferences as the link describes. Or this link http://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files

Comment: @alkis: Excel used "." for numbers >=1000 to format it like "1.000". But 33.014782905578606 is <1000 and even if I turn it of it is still interprets the number as 33014782905578606. I don't think "." is used as a delimiter (";" is as far as I know) because values like 0.4773058891296386 which are <1 are interpreted correctly.

Comment: Maybe check what format the cell uses, maybe `#,####` (one digit before decimal separator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ged rid of the hashtags I simply had to expand the column width. Thanks, OldProgrammer.

The floating point numbers <1 weren't recognized as numbers, hence the point was still there. The ones >=1 were recognized as numbers however the dot was interpreted as the thousands separator while "," was the decimal separator. I had to disable "use system separators" and set custom ones as described [here](http://blogmines.com/blog/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-in-excel-2010/).